# Print statement alignment and padding

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Excuse me if the title is a bit misleading but I was a bit unsure on a relevant title name.

I trying to make a text box around some like the snippet here:

```
Die1 = random.randint(1,10)
Die2 = random.randint(1,10)
Die3 = random.randint(1,10)

if Die1 > Die2:
    print ("+------------------------------+")
    print ("|  Die 1:  |       |    Die 2  |")
    print ("|    %d     |       |      %d    |" % (Die1,Die2))
    print ("+------------------------------+")


else:
    print ("+------------------------------+")
    print ("|  Die 1:  |       |    Die 2  |")
    print ("|    %d     |       |      %d    |" % (Die1,Die2))
    print ("+------------------------------+")
```

This is all dandy if i get a result of 1 digit numbers :

```
+------------------------------+
|  Die 1:  |       |    Die 2  |
|    2     |       |      6    |
+------------------------------+
```

However twp digit numbers will give me this:, another space will be pushed out for two tens.

```
+------------------------------+
|  Die 1:  |       |    Die 2  |
|    10     |       |      2    |
+------------------------------+
```

I could do something like:

```
if Die1 > Die2 and Die1 or Die2 == 10:
    print ("+------------------------------+")
    print ("|  Die 1:  |       |    Die 2  |")
    print ("|      %d     |       |      %d    |" % (Die1,Die2))
    print ("+------------------------------+")
```

Etc... but i'm sure there is a more practical way of doing this.

Is there a way to use a single digit to represent the &s ?, and/or and some padding to allow for a second digit if its needed.

I Had a look at the Python Doc's on the matter and i read some padding options for 0's but nothing that could help me directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`string.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function to pad with spaces: (note that this function works in both python 2 and python 3)

```
"|      {0: >2d}     |       |      {1: >2d}    |".format(Die1,Die2)
```

Inside the `{}`s, the `0` and `1` represent which argument is being referenced, the space after the colon is the padding character, `>` means to right-justify the text, the `2` is the width of the text, and the `d` specifies that the argument is an integer.

Example output:

```
|       2     |       |       9    |
|      10     |       |      12    |
```

Comment: I'd hope he's either using python 2 or python 3!  +1 for the answer though.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty I hope so too. I guess I'm mainly specifying that it works with both versions.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood.  That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Great, works a treat, the 0 and 1 are representing the  order and the 2d representing the places ?, Do you remember where you got this info from. Thanks

Comment: @bennyboy If you click on the link in the post, it'll get you to the definition for the definition (if you scroll down there's a bunch of examples too). I'll put in the answer what they mean though, for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the integers with padded 0:

```
"|    %02d     |       |      %02d    |" % (Die1,Die2)
```